# Collision Check

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to test for collision between bullets within a vector and enemies within another vector. I can access the data fine, but the problem lies in the actual detection of the collision. Funny thing is, it works perfectly when I use hitTestObject, so I don't see why this shouldn't be working. I might be overlooking something, but I'm having a hard time finding it.

Code:

```
for each(var i in eManager.enemyArray)
{
    for each(var j in gManager.gunVector)
    {
        for each (var k in j.bManager.bulletVector)
        {

            // Basically using Pythagorean's theorem but with both sides squared
            // to minimize any process-heavy operations
            if(((i.x - k.x)*(i.x - k.x))+((i.y - k.y)*(i.y - k.y)) <= 4)
            { 
                // Note that when this happens, the enemy dies
                i.kill = true;
            }       

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AustinHenley It's basically going through all the enemies and the bullets of all the guns present and checking whether any collision occurs between the enemies and the bullets.

Comment: I ment what is it doing when you run it, obviously it isn't working as expected so what is happening?

Comment: @AustinHenley I honestly can't describe it too well. The enemies disappear even when the bullets are far from them, and there's no way of telling why it does that.

Comment: Sounds like your coordinates are messed up or for some other reason you are falsely detecting a collision and removing the wrong instance. It has happened to me a million times.

Comment: @AustinHenley That's weird. The coordinates shouldn't be messed up since I added the bullets through stage.addChild() unless I'm missing something (fairly new to AS3/OOP here).

Comment: Could be something as simple as the registration points of your symbols being not in the centre of the graphics.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. I was testing the collision between 2 points and not between a point and a shape. I feel pretty retarded not finding out sooner. Thanks, everyone :)

Comment: If that's the case then you should consider posting an answer to your own question that explains that solution and how you problem solved to find it, helping people down the track with similar issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. Turns out that I was testing the collision between 2 points, not between a point and a shape. My mistake.